# Set Current Location Title And Subtitle - Google Maps SDK IOS

Tags: ios, google-maps-sdk-ios

I've been going about on the internet and have looked at the docs provided by google on trying to find something about this. Set Current Location Title And Subtitle?

What I'm specifically looking for is to set a title and subtitle for the current location "dot". So, when user taps on the dot/current location the title and subtitle appears.

It should work very similar along the lines with GMSMarker. 
I've been able to set a GMSMarker atop of the current location dot, but not really the same result. Here's my code if interested:

//Creating Marker For Current Location//

```
 GMSMarker *CurrentLocationMarker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];

    CLLocation *CurrentLocationNote = GoogleMaps.myLocation;

CurrentLocationMarker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(CurrentLocationNote.coordinate.latitude, CurrentLocationNote.coordinate.longitude);
CurrentLocationMarker.title = @"Current Location";
CurrentLocationMarker.snippet = CurrentLocation;
CurrentLocationMarker.map = GoogleMaps;
```

[image: Just a Sample App, hence all the mess]

Answer (score 4):

Could you do what you're currently doing, but set the icon of the marker to be a transparent image?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I suppose so, but I was thinking more of something like what you see in mkmapview (apple's maps), where you're able to set title and subtitle by simply writing this: MapView.userLocation.subtitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", CurrentLocation]; (Currrent Location is an NSString containing the full address) Is that possible with Google maps sdk for ios? - Daniel Lehmann

Comment: Hi Daniel, no I don't think it does support anything like that, so my suggestion was a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

As you have currently done, you can add a marker at your current location. Now for the second part of showing the full address, you can utilise the [reversegeocode](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/interface_g_m_s_geocoder) service that is available in google maps ios sdk and take the fields [addressline1 and addressline2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/interface_g_m_s_reverse_geocode_result) from the [firstresult](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/interface_g_m_s_reverse_geocode_response#aa9eacc8a77ed3b88831c2baa7eea2290) in the response and append them to the snippet of this marker